# Pronunciation of "улыбаться"

Tags: перевод

The word, to smile: улыбаться. I have tried a new speech engine and it is much better than the ones I used so far but this one is a little tricky in my opinion. The verbs with -ся can be a challenge. :)

I need help with the first few words (see markings).

What is more correct and how do you pronounce?

> улыбаться
>
> "*u**v**i*-bat-tsa"
> or
> "*u**l**i*-bat-tsa"

Comment: Hard 'L'. English 'L' is between Russian hard 'L' and soft 'L'.

Comment: Learn Russian transcription. It is impossible to understand what you mean by those Latin characters.

Comment: I learned the russian alphabet a week ago. If user4419802 and Bazonov picked up what I mean it should be able for you to pick up what I meant. I will learn how to transcribe properly. It would help if you could give me a reference where I find reliable information so I can learn to transcribe.

Comment: Hi Ana! If you're hearing [uvy...], then the speech engine isn't very good. Do you happen to have an Apple computer? If so, there are resident voices that come with it and one of them is the Russian voice, Yuri, who's excellent. Also, you can adjust the speed. If you don't have Apple, you can still hear and buy Yuri here: http://harposoftware.com/en/russian/244-Yuri-Nuance-Voice.html.  He'll pronounce individual words or entire sentences. Good luck with Russian! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using English transcription (not IPA, at which I'm no good):
**oo-ly-BUT-tsa**

The second syllable is without stress, so the '***ы***' can really be pronounces as a *schwa*, so can the last '***а***'.  The sounds 't' and 'ts' are really combined into a single '***ц***', so in Russian you can write the pronunciation as ***у-лы-БА-ца***.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. It was very difficult to hear what the speech machine was saying for the first few letters so I was guessing my way through. I will try to learn your norm of transcription. Thanks once again! I highly appreciate your feedback and input. Большой cпасибо + спокойной ночи!